# How to register a new activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android

I always get an error when I run my created application and based on my research I haven't registered my Activity in the manifest.  How can I register a new activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're using Eclipse,

Goto your `Android Manifest`, goto the `Applications` Tab (at the bottom), click on "Add", Choose Activity. On the right, next to `Name:` Click on `Browse`, to get a list of available activities, just add it and you're set! :)

You could right way just edit the Manifest XML aswell. It's upto you.

Comment: can't find an "add" button or something. maybe outdated?

Comment: @transistor, Yeah, this is from 2010. Android was still in its infancy.

Answer (score 7):

```
    <activity android:name="com.kl.android.ReadSMS.ViewSMS" />
```

Answer (score 7):

just use the class name after '.'
like the following

```
<activity android:name=".ViewSMS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, Go to **AndroidManifest.xml** file and use

```
 <activity android:name="YourPackageName.ClassName">
```

For example,

```
<activity android:name="com.android.favoritetoys.MainActivity">
```

For More [List of `activity` attributes in AndroidManifest.xml](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)