# Android Null Pointer Exception Button

Tags: android, button, nullpointerexception

Ok this may seem like a pointless example but if I can figure this out then the program I am trying to make will work.  So I have two activities test and test two each with one button.

Test 1:

```
package thompson.cameron.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View button = findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
     Intent i = new Intent(this, Test2.class);
     startActivity(i);
     }

}
```

and test2

```
package thompson.cameron.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Test2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main2);

  View test = findViewById(R.id.testButton);
  test.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

 public void onClick(View v){
  switch (v.getId()){
  case R.id.testButton:
   System.exit(1);
  }
 }

}
```

When I click the button on Test it is supposed to launch test2 however it is at this point I get an null pointer exception that I have narrowed down to `test.setOnClickListener(this);` line of code.  Below are my two xml files for the `layout`.  I can get the button to work when I only have one activity but as soon as I add a second `activity` with a different `layout` file it all falls apart

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button
 android:id="@+id/testButton"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="TEST TEST TEST"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

main2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button
 android:id="@+id/testButton"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="TEST2 TEST2 TEST2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm still new at Android programming so thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

In your test.java file give:

```
implements View.OnClickListener
```

Initialize your button as:

```
Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
```

and inside your onClick method, check whether you are clicking button:

```
if(v == testButton) {
//give ur intent code
}
```

There are different ways to perform onClick functionality.
One is the above method which I have mentioned.
Another one is what ankit has mentioned.
Third way is through your layout.

Inside your layout for your button tag, you may give as:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/testButton" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Click" android:onClick="onTestButtonClick" />
```

And inside your class just mention the below details for button:

```
public void onTestButtonClick(View view) {
     //give your intent code
}
```

You may refer to the link also: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/ui-framework-changes-in-android-16.html

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the `Debug perspective` in `Eclipse`
2. Choose the 'Breakpoints' view tab.
3. Select the '`Add Java Exception Breakpoint`' and choose
   `NullPointerException`.
4. Launch your `activity`, either by using 'Debug As...' or attaching
   the debugger to a running instance via DDMS.
5. Execute the offending workflow. It will break on the line that
   caused the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You're not going to spam this on every slightly related question, are you?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that both activities are register at the application's manifest file.

As a side note never call System.exit in your code. You can call finish() to close an Activity and this will bring at the front the previous Activity on the stack.

Comment: if Activity is not registered then I think it should throw exception other than **NPE**

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you haven't typecasted your views to buttons.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button; // Needed to add this import for the button casting below


public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // I have changed View to Button and then typecasted
        // with the "(Button)" the return of findViewById

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Test2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any issues with this. I just completed my first experiment through using the onClickListener implementation through the main class instead of individual anonymous listeners.

Andrew

Comment: A Button is a View, so no need to cast.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you may put the same content view that the button, 
setContentView(R.layout.main); if the button is in that content view, in other case, you will put:

```
setContentView(R.layout.buttoncontentview);
View button = findViewById(R.id.testButton);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
public void onClick(View v){ 
  Intent i = new Intent(this, Test2.class);
  startActivity(i); 
} 
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

sorry for my bad english, but i'm spanish

Answer (score 1):

Implement `OnClickListener` interface

and set  `button.setOnClickListener(this);`

and override

```
public void onClick(View v) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your buttons IDs need to be different in different activities. R.id.testButton would refer to only one button.

Comment: We can have same id names in different layout files. When we give the setContentView(layout), it take ids from that xml only.

Comment: ID's are simply mapped to an intenger, they can (and arguably should) be reused in different layouts but should be unique within the context of a single layout

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.it may work.

```
package thompson.cameron.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Test extends Activity{

      private Button button;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i=new Intent().setClass(Test.this,Test2.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The final solution is that you may modify the AndroidManifest.xml file, i finally solved my error in this link [How to register a new activity in AndroidManifest.xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481903/how-to-register-a-new-activity-in-manifest-xml)

Answer (score 0):

First of all in main.xml and main2.xml chage the button's ids like in below code.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button
 android:id="@+id/testButton"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="TEST TEST TEST"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button
 android:id="@+id/testButton1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="TEST2 TEST2 TEST2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It throws nullpointerexception because of id confict with each other so in your java file use following code to find button.

In Activity 1

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.testButton);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and 
In Activity 2

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.testButton1);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```