# NullPointerException at View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:9938) Android 4.0.3/4.0.4

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Could not find similar questions, so:
I have bunch reports of similar Exceptions. And it doesn't point to any place of my application. I assume this might happend when App is trying to restore state of view and objects that is passed to container are nulls.

I'm using android-support-v4 lib for fragments + [Parcelable](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html&ei=idSmUMHTB8mj4gSAnIDoCg&usg=AFQjCNHXgG4cAKxqG59cOZiKxahK2oLunA&sig2=ooy4UetF-tNrUzSQn-NYSw&cad=rjt) interface to store data inside dialog fragments. Android project target for API 16, using Project API 16.

This crashes appears only on 4.0.3 and 4.0.4 devices according reports.

Does anyone faced such problems?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my/com.my.activities.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:9938)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2318)
at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:9921)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1625)
at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:906)
at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:878)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1100)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
... 12 more
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find the solution? I got the same issue with higher API levels

Comment: No, I haven't. We dropped support for those versions eventually.

Answer (score 2):

Found yet again a dirty work around.

Thanks to Bill Blume for throwing some light on what was creating the problem.

Jus override the onRestoreInstanceState method of your activity and handle the exception something like below.

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exce");
    }
}
```

Thanks again Bil Blume

Answer (score 1):

I have been encountering this bug myself.  Like you, I have only received this error by crash reports.  I have never able to reproduce it myself.  Unfortunately, I have not found a resolution on this.  However, by looking at the Android source code via GrepCode, I believe I have some clues.  In PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(), the crash is occurring within the call to restoreHierarchyState() in the following code fragment:

```
if (mActionBar != null) {
    SparseArray<Parcelable> actionBarStates =
        savedInstanceState.getSparseParcelableArray(ACTION_BAR_TAG);
    mActionBar.restoreHierarchyState(actionBarStates);
}
```

(Taken from http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java#PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

My guess is that the NPE occurs because actionBarStates was null.  It doesn't occur for 4.1 or later because 4.1 added a null check of actionBarStates.

I can't really say whether this is a bug with 4.0.x action bars, with the android support library, or a bug in your action-bar/menu configuration.

Comment: Thanks, but what You suggest to do? I'll try it in next release of our app.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a solution.  My gut feeling is that this is a bug in the support library's handling of 2.x options menus on Android OS 4.0.x, (I am still using 2.x style options menus (onCreateOptionsMenu, onPrepareOptionsMenu) in my app.)  If this is the case, the only workarounds are to (1) stop using the support library, (2) eliminate all options menus, or (3) convert all options menus to 4.x style action bar items.  Given that (1) and (2) are unacceptable to me and I lack the time to do (3), I am just living with the bug at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using intent get / put extras? You have a NullPointerException in the middle of your log, which could be cause by putting a null value to the extras - [Android app unable to start activity componentinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6900437/android-app-unable-to-start-activity-componentinfo)

Comment: Yes, i'm using put/get extras. I already thougth that it might be the reason, and that is why i init all values in non-arg constructor of my object's class (also as in abstract base class). I checked it on different devices and Android API versions it haven't null values passed...

Comment: Did you also check on the device that gets the error? If not, it seems like a good idea to do so - can you please run a check if the value is null before using the extras and print some message to the log to confirm it?

Comment: Yes, i did few test now on Android 4+ devices, and it works fine. Also it was working fine before i explicitly added value initialization in non-arg conctructor...

Comment: @RogerAlien sorry, I am confused by your answer. are you saying you are no longer getting the exception and the problem was device specific?

Comment: I don't have this exception on my devices, BUT i receive this error from bug reports from other users device via GooglePlay report system.