# What is the difference between the up-casting and down-casting?

Tags: primitive-types, downcast, reference-type, upcasting

What is the difference between the up-casting and down-casting with respect to primitive datatypes and referenced datatypes.

For example in primitive types we are saying up-casting is going from lower to higher (int to double) and down-casting is higher to lower(double to int). For this we use cast operator.

But for referenced data types it is in opposite of the previous case. For example animal only contains `callme()` method but dog contains `callme()` and `callme2()` methods then how we can say that animal is higher than dog.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between up-casting and down-casting with respect to class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class)

Answer (score 1):

@user3316746:

Let's use your example of **animal** and **dog**, but also throw **cat** into the mix.

**Animal** is an abstract class that would never be instantiated, and is meant to hold **common attributes and behaviours** of the classes that inherit from it.  So, in this case, the animal class might look like:

```
class Animal {

    // Properties (attributes)
    private int age;

    // Methods (behaviours)
    public void eat();
    public void sleep();
}
```

Both **dog** and **cat** inherit the 'age' property and the 'eat' and 'sleep' methods defined in the 'animal' class, but they can also define new properties and new behaviours specific to that type of animal.

So **cat** could look like:

```
class Cat extends Animal {

    // Methods (behaviours)
    public void purr();
}
```

And **dog** could look like:

```
class Dog extends Animal {

    // Methods (behaviours)
    public void bark();
}
```

So both **dog** and **cat** are types of animals, they both have an age, and they can both eat and sleep.  However, only a cat can purr and only a dog can bark.

The dog and cat classes have more functionality than the base animal class they inherit from, but the animal class is still considered **higher** because it defines attributes and behaviours that are common to both cats and dogs.

Comment: I am not clear with this. I need the different examples for primitive and referenced types.