# Fully qualified generics type casting error overlooked by Java compiler?

Tags: java, generics, casting, compiler-warnings

Generics are knowingly meant for stronger type checking at compile time. However, while studying the official Java tutorial, I ran into this:

```
However, in some cases the compiler knows that a type parameter is always valid and allows the cast. For example:

List<String> l1 = ...;
ArrayList<String> l2 = (ArrayList<String>)l1;  // OK
```

from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#cannotCast.

I've tried and tested this (which fully reflects the documentation):

```
List<String> l1 = new LinkedList<String>();
ArrayList<String> l2 = (ArrayList<String>)l1;  // OK
```

Although everything is pretty explicit (no assignment to an `Object` variable, no wilcarding, etc), the compiler fails to predict the runtime error that shows up afterwards:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

100% puzzled.

Comment: [What is the difference between up-casting and down-casting with respect to class variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class)?

Comment: You're attempting to cast a `List` to `ArrayList`, which gives a runtime exception. Why would there be a compiler error?

Comment: Thank everybody for the clarification. `In some cases`, in the tutorial, was a bit vague. After this I google'd the tutorial site for `downcast` and `upcast` - found nothing, so thanks again for the plus.

Answer (score 1):

Reread the link -- it's not stating you can cast a `LinkedList` to an `ArrayList`. It's stating that you can *downcast* a `List` of `String` to the (presumably programmer-known) type of `ArrayList` of `String`. What they're attempting to illustrate is the difference between the *generic* type parameters. Their first example shows casting from a collection of `Integer` to a collection of `Number`, which is not allowed.

> Typically, you cannot cast to a parameterized type unless it is
>   parameterized by unbounded wildcards. For example:
>
> List li = new ArrayList<>(); 
>   List  ln = (List) li;  // compile-time error
>
> However, in some cases the
>   compiler knows that a type parameter is always valid and allows the
>   cast. For example:
>
> List l1 = ...; 
>   ArrayList l2 = (ArrayList)l1; // OK

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. `In some cases`, in the tutorial, was a bit vague. After this I google'd the tutorial site for `downcast` and `upcast` - found nothing, so thanks again for the plus.