# Why bark method can not be called

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class Animal{
    void run() {
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    void bark() {
    }
}
class Testing{
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Animal d = new Dog();
        d.run();
        d.bark();
    }
}
```

I am trying to call bark method using object of dog class whose reference is stored in Animal class variable. But it is showing me compile time error. Can anyone explain Why?

Comment: I guess the bark problem comes from your inheritance *tree*...

Answer (score 3):

This is how its work.

When compiler try to detect who is `d`.? its see.

```
Animal d
```

Compiler doesn't know know how its created, look at the reference type. So, `d` is an `Animal`.

Now the reference is `Animal`. Does `Animal` have a `bark()` method? no. **ERROR**.

May be `d` is a `Dog` inside but compiler doesn't know that and compiler shouldn't know, Compiler translate what you said about `d` in that case. That's why you getting the error.

Now you can tell that I want `d` to act as `Dog` because I know `d` is a `Dog` by,

```
((Dog) d);
```

and then call `bark()`

```
((Dog) d).bark();
```

So compiler will take `d` as a `Dog` only for this operation.

Comment: then what is the advantage of using Animal d = new Dog()? Isn't better to just use Dog d = new Dog()?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you store your dog in the variable of type `Animal` which is only able to `run()`. There could be another animal `Cat` which isn't able to `bark()`.

If you want to let the dog `bark()` then you need to put in a `Dog` typed variable:

```
Dog rolf = new Dog();
rolf.bark();
```

Comment: Then how can i access bark method?

Comment: @ManishKumar I've extended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `d` as an `Animal`.

However, while internally `d` may be a `Dog`, being stored as an `Animal` will only allow you to use methods declared in `Animal`.

Comment: Then how can i access bark method?

Comment: you will have to either declare `bark()` in `Animal`, or declare `d` as a `Dog` like `Dog d = new Dog();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explicit cast to call it

```
((Dog)d).bark();
```

Comment: You should explain why your code will work so the op will learn

Comment: I did say explicit cast, it's thoroughly explained in the java docs.

Comment: Looking at the op question, it is clear he did not fully understand the concepts of inheritance and polymorphism. Giving a technical, one-line solution is not going to help him much in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can call only the methods defined in the reference type. i.e since the Animal class has only one method ( run() ) you cant call bark() on it, even if its referring to Dog object.

What you are doing is upcasting, you can get to know more about upcasting and downcasting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class)