# java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger

Tags: java, hql

My program has a method that fetches the count of a particular row and convert it into BigInteger:

```
private BigInteger getSameSatPremise(ServiceAgreement sa) {
BigInteger count = BigInteger.ZERO;

    StringBuffer queryHql = new StringBuffer();
    queryHql.append("from Table t1");
    Query query = createQuery(queryHql.toString());
    query.addResult("count", "count(distinct t1.column1)");
    if (query.listSize() > 0) {
        count = (BigInteger) query.firstRow();
    }
    return count;
}
```

The casting works fine when the result from the query is 0. But I get a casting error like below when the result from the query is 2.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.math.BigInteger
```

Can anyone help.

Comment: Why do you think you can cast that? Use `BigInteger.valueOf(query.firstRow())`.

Comment: Methinks this question is reasonable, especially if the OP comes from C++.

Comment: Why are you trying to widen a `long`? If the column is a long type, why not use `long`?

Comment: `casting works fine when the result from the query is 0` No. In that case `query.listSize() > 0` you don't cast. You return the initial value of `count` which is `BigInteger.ZERO`.

Comment: @Tom query.firstRow() is a Object type. Maybe you'll have to do some research next time before answering.

Comment: Since your were inable to define which classes/libraries you're using, it was impossible to do research on that. That `query.firstRow()` returns `Object` instead of `Long` (or `long`) is crucial information and it _needs_ to be in that question. And please, learn the difference between "answering" and commenting.

Answer (score 12):

Java ain't C++, you can't write your own conversion operators.

In Java you need to use explicit functions to do what you want. In your case that's the considerably more verbose

`BigInteger.valueOf(query.firstRow())`

Comment: query.firstRow() is not a Long but an Object. BigInteger.valueOf(query.firstRow()) will not work in this case.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The runtime error implies the type is a `java.lang.Long`.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I have verified that query.firstRow() gives a value of Object datatype

Comment: @VishnuPriyanRangasamy You'll need to cast it to a `Long`, and then use `BigInteger.valueOf` on that.

Comment: @LouisWasserman How can the exception show 'Long' can not be cast, when the method returns 'Object' type?

Comment: @Anmol the method return type is `Object`, but the actual runtime type is `Long`.  This is _easy_ to reproduce: write `Object o = Long.valueOf(2); System.out.println(BigInteger.valueOf((Long) o));`

Comment: Yes, I see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Long is not a subclass of BigInteger, so 'Long is NOT BigInteger'. So, your Long can not be cast to a BigInteger.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

Use static method of BigInteger: `BigInteger.valueOf(long val);` as `BigInteger.valueOf(query.firstRow())`.

And your code works in case of zero results because, you have initialized the `count` with a ZERO of type `BigInteger`. So, in case of zero results, your code does not get into the if statement (no casting is tried) and returns `count` straight away.

You might also want to read about Upcasting and Downcasting in Java.

[What is the difference between up-casting and down-casting with respect to class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class)

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.Long` and `java.math.BigInteger` are in a different hierarchies. They cannot be castes to each other. You can create new `BigInteger` by using `static factory method`:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(yourLong);
```