# Java - How can I check if my scene is in full screen mode?

Tags: java, javafx, fullscreen

```
@FXML
private void opensettings(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Stage stage = null;
    Parent root = null;

    if(event.getSource() == settings && stage.isFullScreen() == true){
        stage = (Stage)settings.getScene().getWindow();
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/Settings.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setTitle("Settings");
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to check if my current stage is running in full screen mode or not. Above is my current java code.

Comment: Isn't `stage.isFullScreen()` working ?

Comment: nope its saying : Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sample.OpenController.opensettings(OpenController.java:75)
 ... 58 more

Comment: Are you calling `stage.isFullScreen()` before initializing the stage?

Comment: @bilesh i initialized it now but it stills jumps from my fullscene "main window" to a not fullscene "settings window" and actually i want that if my "main window" is in fullscene mode the "settings window" schould be in fullscene mode too... :/

Comment: uhm ...  `Window` is no `Stage`. At all - but a `Stage` is a `Window`, not the other way around. You're doing a lot of illegal casting up there, that may be your core problem. Casting is *(very)* bad - in pretty much any language other than C / C++ and everyone who tells you otherwise simply is ... inexperienced, a hobbyist at best. Sorry. At least do some **checked** casting, that'll prevent `NullPointerException` or `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score -3):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html), a `Stage` is a `Window` but a `Window` doesnt know anything about its subclass `Stage`. You should read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class) if you want to learn about upcasting and downcasting.
In your case, `Window` has been constructed as `Stage` **but** was stored as `Window` so all of the `Stage`-specific fields are now void.

Conclusion : do not downcast if you're inexperienced. At all.