# Why the return value of findViewById() can be cast to Button?But Button is one of subclass of View

Tags: java, android

And in java

```
    class Person{}
    class Student extends Person{}
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Person person = new Person();
            Student student = (Student)person;
        }
    }
```

There is a 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Person cannot be cast to Student"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simulate the case in Android with your example, it should be like this:

```
class Person{}
class Student extends Person{}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = getPerson();
        Student student = (Student) person;
    }

    private Person getPerson() {
        return new Student();
    }
}
```

Which is perfectly OK.

This means the object that `findViewById()` returns, is actually a `Button`, but up-casted to `View`. Later you need to down-cast that to the `Button`.

Comment: Where can I find something more about how findViewById() achieve?

Comment: Check out `View` class [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html). This method is simple, you just need to cast the return value to whatever view type you've used in the xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing down casting

Below down casting is not allowed. Because person is not instance of Student or Student's subclass.

```
Student student = (Student)person;
```

Below down casting is ok. because the result of findview is instace of Button.

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById...
```

Refer this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23414798/5183999