# c# upcasting is always allowed

Tags: java, c#, casting, polymorphism

In **Java**,

> "Up-casting is casting to a supertype, while downcasting is casting to
>   a subtype. Supercasting is always allowed, but subcasting involves a
>   type check and can throw a ClassCastException."

([What is the difference between up-casting and down-casting with respect to class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class))

Is upcasting also *always* allowed in **C#**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed, since a subclass is a particularization of the ancestor class.

Example:

Let us consider the case when we have a `class` called `Bird`, another called `Sparrow` and a third one `Eagle`. `Sparrow` and `Eagle` are inherited from `Bird`. `Sparrows` differ from `Eagles` greatly, but they are `Bird`s. So, if you want to have a `Collection` of `Bird`s for some reason, then you can have `Eagle` and `Sparrow` objects in that `Collection` at the same time, since they are still `Birds`, if only *specific* `Bird`s.

Answer (score 1):

yes, up-casting is allowed :-)

[Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

OOP principles state that you can *always* upcast; however, unlike **Java** with very restricted number of *primitive classes*, **.Net** implementation allows to declare `struct` types, some of them are *weird* counter-examples with *boxing*:

```
 TypedReference reference = new TypedReference();

 // Compile time error here! Even if Object is the base type for all types
 Object o = (Object)reference;
```

Technically, `TypedReference` is an `Object`:

```
 Object
   ValueType
     TypedReference
```

you can easily check it:

```
 Console.Write(typeof(TypedReference).BaseType.BaseType == typeof(Object) 
   ? "TypedReference derived from Object via ValueType" 
   : "Very strange");
```

but in order to be represented as `Object` instance (via cast) it should be *boxed* which can't be done.