# Casting item to "this" in static method

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to tell TypeScript that a static method returns an object that called the method?

I have this base class:

```
export default class model {
  public static create() {
    let t = new this() as this
    // set extra information here
    return t
  }
}
```

I then extend the class like this:

```
export default class purchases extends model { /* extra methods */ }
```

I then call it like this:

```
let p = purchases.create({ my: 'options' })
```

TypeScript then tells me that `p` is of type `model` when actually it should be of type `purchases`.

When I cast `t` to `this` or say `public static create(): this` I get this error:

> A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface.

What can I do to say that "This static method returns an instance of the object that called it"?

Comment: There is no `this` in static methods, because there is no "object that called it".

Comment: then how come I can call `new this()`?

Comment: Oh, this (no pun intended) may be a thing I wasn't aware of in TS: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863

Comment: huh... okay so it seems as if it isn't possible at the moment, without using some sort of workaround...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might just be to downcast the instance

```
class model {
  public static create() {
    let t = new this();
    // set extra information here
    return t;
  }
}

class purchases extends model { /* extra methods */ }

let p = purchases.create() as purchases; // downcast
```

Comment: That is the "workaround" that I decided to go with. I hope they implement something that is described within the link above.

Comment: Note that this is a downcast, not an upcast - see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class