# error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short. I don't know why i'm getting this error message

Tags: java

```
public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       int a=10,b=20;
       short c = (a<b)?a:b;
       System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

**this is my program and I got below error why I'm not getting**

```
"Demo.java:6: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short
short c = (a<b)?a:b;
1 error"
```

**And I write "final" with variable declaration and it works fine. But why does this happen?**

```
public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final int a=10,b=20;
        short c = (a<b)?a:b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question, you are basically ***Down-casting*** the **int** data type to **short** in both the cases which is not acceptable in Java. To describe in detail, below are the detailed description:-

**Case 1:-**

```
public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
       int a=10,b=20;
       short c = (a<b)?a:b;
       System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

In this scenario, you are just ***down-casting*** data type from **int** to **short** which is throwing

> error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to short

**Case 2:-**

```
public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final int a=10,b=20;
        short c = (a<b)?a:b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

> In this scenario, since you have declared your variables viz. a & b as
>   ***final***. As a result, both the values becomes ***CONSTANT*** for variable c. It means for the variable c, the values of a & b won't get
>   changed & it has been finalized to 20 which is in range of **short**
>   data type (-32,768 to 32,767). Therefore, you won't get any error
>   unless & until you keep the value within the range.

**Real Test case:-**

```
public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final int a=32768,b=32788;
        short c = (a<b)?a:b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

*Compile this class & see the magic! You'll again get the same error.*

> > For your further understanding, please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class) here to get a clear picture in general.
>
> Moral of the story:- ***Just do not downcast your data type!!***

Answer (score 2):

This is specified in the Java Language Specification [§5.2 Assignment Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> ...
>
> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

The expression with ternary operator that you have used in the second snippet is a constant expression, because all the variables used in that expression are `final`. In addition, `10` is representable in `short`. Therefore, a narrowing primitive conversion from `int` to `short` is allowed.

This makes sense, doesn't it? The compiler knows all about the values of the final variables, so this can surely be allowed.

In the first case however, `a` and `b` are not constant variables, so `(a<b)?a:b` is not a constant expression, so an explicit cast is needed:

```
short c = (short)((a<b)?a:b);
```