# Up-casting and down-casting confusion over a method in Java

Tags: java

I am still confused about the general difference between upcasting and downcasting. 
How is it that sum of `v23` is `132`? Shouldn't it be `77` after upcasting?

I realize that overriding comes to take the place but then how can you get the access to the method of super-class if the function below seems to always refer to the method of the subclass?

[image]

Comment: the variable is declared to be `vec2` but the instance is still `vec3`, and that has overridden the method - the reason for overriding is exactly to use the overriding method instead of the original (e.g. `toString()`, ) .

Comment: Please never post code as image. Post it as text.

Comment: @Nathan Lee Please [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class] hit the link before & get your brain enlightened with the concept of Up-casting & Down-casting in Java. Probably, it is the best material at SO to get your doubt/confusion clarified!!

Answer (score 0):

> I realize that overriding comes to take the place ....

Correct!

> but then how can you get the access to the method of super-class if the function below seems to always refer to the method of the subclass?

You can't gain access to the method that has been overridden.  That is fundamental to Java overriding.

Casting won't help you.  Your `v23` variable holds a reference to an object that is fundamentally and irrevocably a `vec3` instance.

Thus, you are calling the version of `sum` that adds all 3 numbers: `33 + 44 + 55` -> `132`.