# Cannot cast Comparable to a class which implements it

Tags: java, casting, genetics

I'm trying to create a genetic ArrayList of my class Team but I can't cast Comparable to T despite that T extends Comparable

(I tried extends Comparable without putting < T > and same problem is happening)

```
public class ArrayList<T extends Comparable>
{
    static int MaxSize = 1003;//some random maximum size for our array lists
    public int Size = 0;
    public int Capacity = 0;
    T[] MyList;
    public ArrayList()//Default Constructor
    {
        this(MaxSize);
    }
    public ArrayList(int Capacity)
    {

        MyList = (T[]) new Comparable[Capacity]; // Casting
    }
}
public class Team implements Comparable<Team>
{
    public String Name;
    public int Points;
    public int GamesCount;
    public int Wins;
    public int Loses;
    public int GoalDifference;//Goals Scored - Goals Against
    public int GoalsScored;
    public int GoalsAgainst;
    public Team(String s)
    {
      Name = s;
      Points = 0;
      GamesCount = 0;
      Wins = Loses = 0;
      GoalDifference = GoalsAgainst = GoalsScored = 0;
    }
}
public class Test
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
     ArrayList<Team> Teams = new ArrayList<Team>(10);
            for(int i = 0 ;i < 10;i++)
            {
                String TeamName = in.next();
                Teams.MyList[i] = new Team(TeamName);//exception here
            }
  }
}
```

I am getting the following exception. Many thanks in advance for your help.

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Comparable; cannot be cast to [LTeam;
    at Test.main(Test.java:21)**

Comment: Casting an `Animal` to a `Cat` will not work. The animal might also be a `Dog` or anything. Only the other way around makes sense, casting a `Cat` to an `Animal`. Since all cats are also animals.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Maybe I'm missing something but I can't reproduce the problem using Java 11.0.2. _Unrelated_: Please learn Java naming conventions and use them; doing so makes it easier for other Java developers to read your code.

Comment: Java Version 8 update 181

Answer (score 2):

That's obvious, just think about it for a second.

```
new Comparable[Capacity];
```

Here you're creating an `array` which will contain `Comparable` elements.
Then you're trying to **downcast** it to an `array` of `Team`, which means trying to use a more specific type, and which is not allowed ([Upcasting and downcasting in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class)), and as you see, throws a `ClassCastException`.

As your `array` will contain only types which `extends Comparable`, you can have a `Comparable` `array` inside your `ArrayList` implementation.

```
Comparable[] MyList;
```

Then you can initialize it without casting

```
MyList = new Comparable[Capacity];
```

---

And remember to implement the `Comparable#compareTo` method in your `Team` class, otherwise the code won't compile.

---

You asked for an example.

```
public class ArrayList<T extends Comparable> {
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 1000;
    private final Comparable<T>[] list;

    public ArrayList() {
        this(MAX_SIZE);
    }

    public ArrayList(int capacity) {
        list = new Comparable[capacity]; // Casting
    }

    public T get(final int index) {
        return (T) list[index];
    }

    public void set(final int index, final T value) {
        list[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Usage is pretty simple

```
final ArrayList<Team> teamArrayList = new ArrayList<>(3);
teamArrayList.set(0, new Team("One"));
teamArrayList.set(1, new Team("Two"));
teamArrayList.set(2, new Team("Three"));

final String name = teamArrayList.get(0).Name;
```

As you extended the `Comparable<T>` interface, you need to implement it

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a
>   negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object

A basic example is

```
@Override
public int compareTo(final Team other) {
    return name.compareTo(other.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the issue but that doesn't help me to achieve my goals since team has string and numbers but comparable doesn't. how can I make a list of teams in that case?

Comment: @ziadxkabakibi I'm eating, I'll show you an example later

Comment: I can't use Teams.MyList[i].Name now, it doesn't compile:
Error:(85, 51) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Name
  location: interface java.lang.Comparable

Comment: @ziadxkabakibi Understood what you mean. That's because you're now dealing with a Comparable object.

Comment: @ziadxkabakibi see updated answer, I included incapsulation of the array and appropriate casting.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `T` is `Team`.

`Team` IS-A `Comparable`. Hence, you can cast `Team` to `Comparable`.

But every `Comparable` is not a `Team`. Therefore, `Comparable` cannot be cast to `Team`.

Answer (score 0):

watch this statement: `MyList = (T[]) new Comparable[Capacity];` it initializes an array from Comparable interface and put it in to MyList field with type of  `Team[]`.
you can test it with:

```
{
    MyList = (T[]) new Comparable[Capacity]; // Casting
    System.out.println( MyList.getClass().toString());
}
```

it writes `class [Ljava.lang.Comparable;` in output... so in the first attempt to access this field from outside of class you will get ClassCastException even by calling length in test method like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MArrayList<Team> Teams = new MArrayList<Team>(10);
        int length = Teams.MyList.length; // this line throws ClassCastException 
        ....
    }
}
```

To solve your problem I suggest change your ArrayList class like this:

```
public class ArrayList<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    ...
    Comparable<T>[] MyList;
    ...
    public ArrayList(int Capacity)
    {
        MyList = new Comparable[Capacity]; // Casting
    }
}
```