# What is the purpose of downcasting and upcasting at the same time?

Tags: java, downcast

I have a parent class Animal and a child class Dog extends Animal.

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Animal animal1 = (Dog) dog;
Animal animal2 = (Animal) dog;
```

I just learned about downcasting and I'd like to ask what is the purpose of doing downcasting and upcasting at the same time?

Comment: Where exactly does your example code downcast and upcast at the same time?

Comment: please check the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class/23414798#23414798

Comment: The casts in your code are unnecessary.

Comment: I'm not sure what your code has to do with your question, but in any case, both explicit casts in that code are unnecessary.

Comment: 1. There is no downcast here. 2. Neither typecast has any point whatsoever. The first one merely asserts the *status quo,* and the second one is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `Dog` inherit from `Animal`? I will assume yes.

To answer the question - There is no point to do that. It can be simplified such as:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Animal animal1 = dog;
Animal animal2 = dog;
```

You may want to downcast when the variables (`animal1` or `animal2`) are from type `Dog` and you have an object from another type that `Dog` inherits from (e.g. `Animal`) - but be sure that that object really is `Dog`.