# Why can't the compiler resolve the symbol for instance method in this case?

Tags: java, interface

Suppose a class MyClass implements an interface MyInterface, and it has its own instance method let's say foo().
When i create an instance of MyClass like this:

```
MyInterface myClass = new MyClass();
```

The compiler wouldn't let me access its instance method without an explicit casting:

```
myClass.foo();  // Can't resolve symbol
((MyClass) myClass).foo(); // this is okay
```

Even though the compiler obviously knows myClass is an instance of MyClass:

```
if(myClass instanceof MyClass)
  System.out.println(myClass.getClass().getName()); //this will print "MyClass"
```

Why do i need to use cast for compiler to allow me to access the instance method?

Comment: Because **you told** the compiler to treat `myClass` as a `MyInterface` instance, so it can only access `MyInterface` methods. The compiler is doing what you asked it to do. If you want to call `MyClass` methods (without casting), then you would use a `MyClass`-type variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between up-casting and down-casting with respect to class variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414090/what-is-the-difference-between-up-casting-and-down-casting-with-respect-to-class)

Comment: This demonstrates polymorphism. You can treat instances of MyClass as MyClass, My instance or Object depending on the type of the variable declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *meaning* of the line `MyInterface myClass = new MyClass()` is, "Create a new `MyClass`, and then forget about all its features except those defined in the interface `MyInterface`."

When you refer to "the compiler obviously knows myClass is an instance of MyClass," you're not actually correct: it's *not* the compiler that knows that, but the *runtime.*  The *compiler* was told to forget that information, and it did.

Answer (score 0):

It might be of type `MyClass` but you are treating it as a `MyInterface`. When you do `A myVar = new B();` you only have access to whatever you can access in `A` even though `myVar`is of type `B`.