# Android Studio: Adding Kotlin to existing Java app ends up in "Internal error: unexpected lint return value -1" when building

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, build

I'm adding Kotlin to my existing Java app (I first have to say I've already done it to another of my apps with no problems at all) and after following all required initial steps I always get an "Internal error: unexpected lint return value -1" with no error details when building.

This is the relevant part of my project's grade file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.0'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
...
}
```

This is the relevant parts of my module's build .gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
android {
  ...
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I've tried all recommendations found here: [How to Use Kotlin in an Existing Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025758/how-to-use-kotlin-in-an-existing-android-app) to no avail.

I've also tried clearing all the cache with:

```
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches/
```

to no avail also.

What can I do? I'm not even getting details about the problem.

[image]

Edit 1:

Now I was able to see the complete build log:

```
Executing tasks: [:DTO:clean, :Core:clean, :Repository:clean, :app:clean, :Security:clean, :Services:clean, :Global:clean, :Background:clean, :Common:clean, :Exception:clean, :Core:assembleDebug, :DTO:assembleDebug, :Repository:assembleDebug, :Global:assembleDebug, :app:assembleDebug, :Security:assembleDebug, :Services:assembleDebug, :Exception:assembleDebug, :Background:assembleDebug, :Common:assembleDebug] in project /Users/JohnDoe/StudioProjects/android_myapp

Starting Gradle Daemon...
Gradle Daemon started in 493 ms

> Configure project :
The RepositoryHandler.jcenter() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. JFrog announced JCenter's sunset in February 2021. Use mavenCentral() instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#jcenter_deprecation
    at build_e2801rmseiq7s1of4dy7020et$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall(/Users/JohnDoe/StudioProjects/android_myapp/build.gradle:5)
    (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

> Task :DTO:clean
> Task :Core:clean
> Task :Repository:clean
> Task :app:clean
> Task :Security:clean
> Task :Services:clean
> Task :Global:clean
> Task :Background:clean
> Task :Common:clean
> Task :Exception:clean
> Task :Core:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Core:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Core:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :Core:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :Core:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :Core:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :Core:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Core:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :Core:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :Core:generateDebugResValues
> Task :Core:generateDebugResources
> Task :Core:packageDebugResources
> Task :Core:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :Core:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :Core:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :Core:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Core:packageDebugAssets
> Task :Core:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Core:prepareDebugArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Core:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Core:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :Core:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :DTO:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :DTO:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Core:writeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :DTO:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :DTO:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :DTO:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :DTO:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :DTO:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :DTO:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :DTO:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :DTO:generateDebugResValues
> Task :DTO:generateDebugResources
> Task :Core:processDebugManifest
> Task :DTO:packageDebugResources
> Task :DTO:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :DTO:processDebugManifest
> Task :DTO:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :DTO:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :DTO:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :DTO:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :DTO:packageDebugAssets
> Task :DTO:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :DTO:prepareDebugArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :DTO:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :DTO:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :Common:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Common:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Global:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Global:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :DTO:writeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :Global:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :Common:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :Repository:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Repository:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Repository:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :Repository:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :Repository:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :Repository:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :Repository:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :Global:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Common:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Common:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :Common:generateDebugResValues
> Task :Common:generateDebugResources
> Task :Common:packageDebugResources
> Task :Common:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :Global:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Core:generateDebugRFile
> Task :Global:generateDebugResValues
> Task :Global:generateDebugResources
> Task :Common:processDebugManifest
> Task :Global:packageDebugResources
> Task :Global:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :Global:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :Global:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :Global:processDebugManifest
> Task :Common:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :Common:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Repository:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Repository:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :Repository:generateDebugResValues
> Task :Repository:generateDebugResources
> Task :Repository:packageDebugResources
> Task :Repository:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :Core:compileDebugKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :Repository:processDebugManifest

> Task :Core:extractDebugAnnotations FAILED
/Users/JohnDoe/StudioProjects/android_myapp/Core/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug does not exist

> Task :Core:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :Core:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Core:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles
> Task :Core:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :Repository:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :DTO:generateDebugRFile
> Task :Repository:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :Repository:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :Repository:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Repository:packageDebugAssets
> Task :Repository:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Repository:prepareDebugArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Repository:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Repository:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :Repository:writeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :Core:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :Global:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :Global:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :Global:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :Global:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :Global:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :Global:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :Global:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Global:packageDebugAssets
> Task :Global:prepareDebugArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Global:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Global:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Global:writeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :Background:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Background:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Services:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Services:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Services:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :Background:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :Background:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Services:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues
> Task :app:generateDebugResources
> Task :app:dataBindingMergeGenClassesDebug
> Task :Background:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Background:generateDebugResValues
> Task :Background:generateDebugResources
> Task :Background:packageDebugResources
> Task :Services:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Services:generateDebugResValues
> Task :Services:generateDebugResources
> Task :Services:packageDebugResources
> Task :DTO:compileDebugKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :DTO:extractDebugAnnotations
> Task :DTO:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :DTO:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :DTO:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles
> Task :DTO:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :DTO:syncDebugLibJars
> Task :Global:generateDebugRFile
> Task :DTO:bundleDebugAar
> Task :DTO:assembleDebug
> Task :DTO:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :app:dataBindingTriggerDebug
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :Background:writeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :Common:writeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :Services:writeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :Background:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :Common:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :Core:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :DTO:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :Global:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :Background:processDebugManifest
> Task :Repository:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :Services:extractDeepLinksDebug
> Task :Services:processDebugManifest
> Task :Background:compileDebugLibraryResources
> Task :Background:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :Services:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :Common:compileDebugLibraryResources
> Task :Core:compileDebugLibraryResources
> Task :DTO:compileDebugLibraryResources
> Task :Global:compileDebugLibraryResources
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :Repository:compileDebugLibraryResources
> Task :Services:compileDebugLibraryResources

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources
/Users/JohnDoe/StudioProjects/android_myapp/app/src/main/res/values-zh/attrs.xml:6:4: Ignoring configuration 'zh' for <declare-styleable> tag.
/Users/JohnDoe/StudioProjects/android_myapp/app/src/main/res/values-zh/attrs.xml:2:4: Ignoring configuration 'zh' for <declare-styleable> tag.
/Users/JohnDoe/StudioProjects/android_myapp/app/src/main/res/values-zh/attrs.xml:10:4: Ignoring configuration 'zh' for <declare-styleable> tag.
/Users/JohnDoe/StudioProjects/android_myapp/app/src/main/res/values-zh/styles.xml:76:5: Ignoring configuration 'zh' for <declare-styleable> tag.

> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata
> Task :app:dataBindingGenBaseClassesDebug
> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths
> Task :Background:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :Services:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :Services:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :Background:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :Background:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :Background:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :Background:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Background:packageDebugAssets
> Task :Common:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :Common:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :Common:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Common:packageDebugAssets
> Task :Services:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :Services:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :Services:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Services:packageDebugAssets
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :Background:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :Common:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :Core:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :DTO:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :Services:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compressDebugAssets
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
> Task :Global:compileDebugKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :Common:generateDebugRFile
> Task :Global:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :Global:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug

> Task :Global:extractDebugAnnotations FAILED
/Users/JohnDoe/StudioProjects/android_myapp/Global/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug does not exist

> Task :Global:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Global:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles
> Task :Global:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :Global:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :app:processDebugManifestForPackage
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :DTO:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug
> Task :Background:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :Core:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug
> Task :Background:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :Background:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :Common:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :Common:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :Common:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :Core:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :DTO:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :Global:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug
> Task :Global:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :Repository:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :Services:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :Services:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :Services:copyDebugJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions
> Task :Security:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Security:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Security:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :Security:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :Security:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :Security:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :Security:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :Security:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Security:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :Security:generateDebugResValues
> Task :Security:generateDebugResources
> Task :Security:packageDebugResources
> Task :Security:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :Common:compileDebugKotlin NO-SOURCE

> Task :Common:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :Common:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :Common:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :Common:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug
> Task :Repository:generateDebugRFile
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :Security:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :Security:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :Security:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :Security:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Security:processDebugManifest
> Task :Security:packageDebugAssets
> Task :Security:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Security:prepareDebugArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Security:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Security:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :Security:generateDebugRFile
> Task :Services:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :Security:writeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :Security:compileDebugKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :Security:extractDebugAnnotations
> Task :Security:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :Security:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Security:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles
> Task :Security:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :Security:syncDebugLibJars
> Task :Security:bundleDebugAar
> Task :Security:assembleDebug
> Task :Services:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :Repository:compileDebugKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :Services:generateDebugRFile
> Task :Repository:extractDebugAnnotations
> Task :Repository:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :Repository:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Repository:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles
> Task :Repository:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :Repository:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :Repository:syncDebugLibJars
> Task :Repository:bundleDebugAar
> Task :Repository:assembleDebug
> Task :Repository:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :Services:prepareDebugArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Services:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Exception:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Exception:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Exception:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :Exception:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :Exception:mergeDebugNativeLibs NO-SOURCE
> Task :Exception:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :Repository:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug
> Task :Exception:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies
> Task :Background:generateDebugRFile
> Task :Services:compileDebugKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :Services:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :Services:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :Services:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :Services:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug
> Task :Services:extractDebugAnnotations
> Task :Services:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Services:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles
> Task :Exception:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Services:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :Exception:generateDebugBuildConfig
> Task :Services:syncDebugLibJars
> Task :Services:bundleDebugAar
> Task :Services:assembleDebug
> Task :Exception:generateDebugResValues
> Task :Exception:generateDebugResources
> Task :Exception:packageDebugResources
> Task :Exception:parseDebugLocalResources
> Task :Exception:javaPreCompileDebug
> Task :Exception:mergeDebugShaders
> Task :Exception:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :Exception:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Exception:processDebugManifest
> Task :Background:compileDebugKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :Background:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :Background:bundleLibResDebug NO-SOURCE
> Task :Background:bundleLibCompileToJarDebug
> Task :Background:bundleLibRuntimeToDirDebug
> Task :Exception:packageDebugAssets
> Task :Exception:generateDebugRFile
> Task :Exception:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :Exception:compileDebugKotlin NO-SOURCE
> Task :Exception:extractDebugAnnotations
> Task :Exception:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
> Task :Exception:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Exception:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles
> Task :Exception:prepareDebugArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Exception:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Exception:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :Exception:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :Exception:writeDebugAarMetadata
> Task :Exception:syncDebugLibJars
> Task :Exception:bundleDebugAar
> Task :Exception:assembleDebug
> Task :Background:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :Background:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :Background:extractDebugAnnotations
> Task :Background:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Background:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles
> Task :Background:prepareDebugArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Background:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
> Task :Background:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :Common:stripDebugDebugSymbols NO-SOURCE
> Task :Background:syncDebugLibJars
> Task :Background:bundleDebugAar
> Task :Background:assembleDebug
> Task :Common:copyDebugJniLibsProjectAndLocalJars
> Task :Common:extractDebugAnnotations
> Task :Common:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Common:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles
> Task :Common:prepareDebugArtProfile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Common:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :Common:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :Common:syncDebugLibJars
> Task :Common:bundleDebugAar
> Task :Common:assembleDebug
> Task :app:processDebugResources
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug
> Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
> Task :app:packageDebug
> Task :app:createDebugApkListingFileRedirect
> Task :app:assembleDebug

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Core:extractDebugAnnotations'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.AndroidLintWorkAction
   > Internal error: unexpected lint return value -1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Global:extractDebugAnnotations'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.lint.AndroidLintWorkAction
   > Internal error: unexpected lint return value -1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
264 actionable tasks: 237 executed, 27 up-to-date
```

But still not being able to find much information about the "Task :extractDebugAnnotations FAILED" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, don't know why, but after removing

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

from my 'Core' and 'Global' modules build.gradle now the app builds successfully.

I don't know why the other modules accept the apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' in build.gradle and not 'Core' and 'Global' and I don't even know if I'll be able to use Kotlin in those two modules then, but for the moment the app builds just fine.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed that line and resolve the error when build. Because of my java project doesn't have any kotlin file, so it will not auto generate kotlin classes => build task looking files in "build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug" and there are does not exist which cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. 3 of 5 modules in my project generated errors, but 2 of them worked perfectly fine. Solution was quite unusual, as it required only to create empty Kotlin file in each of the modules. It looks like after adding Kotlin plugin to the module, it has to have at least one Kotlin file or it will generate error.

Answer (score 0):

```
kapt.include.compile.classpath=true
```

or remove `kapt.include.compile.classpath`