# Having trouble linking an intent to an activity

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

Alright, so I have been working on this code for over two days trying to find the error in my code.  The problem I have is having an intent get an activity.  I get an "ActivityNotFoundException" and that there is no activity found to handle the intent.  I know that the problem is the naming convention I have been using.  I just can't find it.

The problem occurs when I click on the "Yes" button in the first activity.

Here is the past for the java souce file, android manifest file, and the positive java file

http://pastie.org/pastes/4325906/text

I am following the book Beginning Android Application Development by Wei-Meng Lee.

Thank you very much in advanced for your help and support.  I can believe that it get's tiring answering questions that we have.

Answer (score 0):

You get This Error if:

1. You have **not Registered** your Activity in the **Manifest** file.
2. **Misspelled** your Activity Name if you have registered.

So please check the Activity Name if you have registered and it's **Case Sensitive** so you are required to register it with the exact the same name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I went here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481903/how-to-register-a-new-activity-in-manifest-xml

and registered the activity.  That did not work so I deleted the project and started a new project.  I again registered the activity and I get the same error.  I think it might be the intent  and intent filter.  I am trying to make those work.