# trying to open new activity from fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I am trying to open new activity from a fragment,but it is give error of closing app when using this code. Pls help in what code is added into onclick methode for call the another activity.i am getting problem in following code.

```
package info.androidhive.summit;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class CommunityFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

   public CommunityFragment(){}
  Button btn;
  @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);

    btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this); 

    return rootView;
    }

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub


     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),trail.class);
       getActivity().startActivity(intent);


       Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), 
         "Button is clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

   }
 }
```

Comment: Where to get the error log. i am trying to open apk

Comment: post your manifest file...

Comment: Get logcate read following tutorial. http://www.itcsolutions.eu/2011/09/11/android-tutorial-7-how-to-debug-the-android-mobile-application-with-logcat/

Comment: Have you added your `trail` activity to your manifest file??

Comment: show your manifest...

Comment: I request you to try the solution I have posted below. I believe it will get you the result you want ... do let me know how that goes!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Start an activity from a fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478105/start-an-activity-from-a-fragment)

Comment: mainfestlink -https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B30bI3jv9zB0OTc4R1lRVEp6dkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: just an advice : A fragment should not start an activity, the parent activity should make the call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activity you're trying to start isn't declared in your manifest. Add this to your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".trail" />
```

Comment: Mind to explain why this is a/the solution?

Comment: Edited the answer with appropriate explanation.

Comment: thanks @max59 for your very appreciable code it work like charm for me

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), trail.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

You were using the `Button` inside `onCreateView`, but you can't use the `View` before it is attached.
Add the code show below & don't forget to remove the `Button` you created inside `onCreateView`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this); 
}
```

P.S : Let me if it works or not

Comment: Viewroot cannot be resolved