# Android how to start a new Activity from an activity class called by a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm having some issues starting an activity in an Activity class that is called by a Fragment class (technically a PageAdapter inner class... the Android tab example is odd).

One of the tabs contains a list and I'd like to start a new activity when an item is clicked. I currently have a separate activity class which handles the list and interactions.

I've tried quite a few things such as getting the activity in the fragment and passing through the constructor. As well I have tried just about everything mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478105/start-an-activity-from-a-fragment) stackoverflow thread with no avail.

Currently in the PageAdapter (Non essential code omitted)

```
 public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
 .
 .
 View view;
 .
 case 1:
     view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.forum,
                            container, false);
     lva = new ListViewActivity(view);
     break;
```

This is to create a new a instance of the activity which will populate the view and listen for clicks. From this class I'd like to startActivity() with a new intent. Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: `ListViewActivity` is Activity,Fragment or normal java class ?

Comment: Then instead of Creating object display Activity using `startActivity`

Comment: Thanks for the idea but, it's a tab'd application (sorry I didn't make that clear) so it would kind of break flow if just one tab was a separate activity

Comment: Use getActivity(). startActivity(getActivity(), ListViewActivity.class)