# Click On An Item In RecyclerView Contained In A Fragment To Open New Activity With Passed Data

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclick, android-recyclerview

I have a MainActivity and Three Fragments with recyclerViews inside the three fragments, the recyclerview contain two textviews, i want the user to click on the recyclerview and the text in should be passed on to the new activity, i am a little bit new so i would appreciate it if you can give me detailed code and some explanation.

I want to click on an item in the recyclerview and that should open a new activity, data(text) should be passed from the recyclerview to the new activity.

Here is my code for the HymnModel.java

```
public class HymnModel {

String title;
String song;


HymnModel(String title, String song){
    this.title=title;
    this.song=song;
}

public String getTitle() {return title;
}

public String getSong() {
    return song;
}
}
```

Here is the code for ItemVeiwHolder.java

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.tutorialsbuzz.recyclerview.R;

public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

public TextView title_textview;
public TextView song_textview;



public ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setClickable(true);
    title_textview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
    song_textview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.song);

}

public void bind(HymnModel hymnModel) {
    title_textview.setText(hymnModel.getTitle());
    song_textview.setText(hymnModel.getSong());

}


}
```

Here is my Adapter class

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.tutorialsbuzz.recyclerview.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder> {

private List<HymnModel> mCountryModel;
private List<HymnModel> mOriginalCountryModel;

public RVAdapter(List<HymnModel> mCountryModel) {
    this.mCountryModel = mCountryModel;
    this.mOriginalCountryModel = mCountryModel;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {
    final HymnModel model = mCountryModel.get(i);
    itemViewHolder.bind(model);
}

@Override
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new ItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCountryModel.size();
}

public void setFilter(List<HymnModel> countryModels){
    mCountryModel = new ArrayList<>();
    mCountryModel.addAll(countryModels);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

 }
```

Here is the code for one my fragments

```
public class TabOneFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

private RecyclerView recyclerview;
private List<HymnModel> mHymnModel;
private RVAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_one_fragment, container, false);

    recyclerview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    int numOfSongs = 32;


    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    String [] titles = {HymnTitles.hymnTitle1, HymnTitles.hymnTitle2, HymnTitles.hymnTitle3, HymnTitles.hymnTitle4, HymnTitles.hymnTitle5,
            HymnTitles.hymnTitle6, HymnTitles.hymnTitle7, HymnTitles.hymnTitle8, HymnTitles.hymnTitle9, HymnTitles.hymnTitle10, HymnTitles.hymnTitle11,
            HymnTitles.hymnTitle12};

    String [] songs = {Hymns.hymn1.substring(width/5), Hymns.hymn2, Hymns.hymn3, Hymns.hymn4, Hymns.hymn5, Hymns.hymn6, Hymns.hymn7, Hymns.hymn8, Hymns.hymn9, Hymns.hymn10, Hymns.hymn11, Hymns.hymn12};

    mHymnModel = new ArrayList<>();



    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        mHymnModel.add(new HymnModel(i + "." + " " + titles[i], "  " + songs[i]));
    }

    adapter = new RVAdapter(mHymnModel);
    recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(item,
            new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when collapsed
                    adapter.setFilter(mHymnModel);
                    return true; // Return true to collapse action view
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    // Do something when expanded
                    return true; // Return true to expand action view
                }
            });
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    final List<HymnModel> filteredModelList = filter(mHymnModel, newText);
    adapter.setFilter(filteredModelList);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}


private List<HymnModel> filter(List<HymnModel> models, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<HymnModel> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (HymnModel model : models) {
        final String text = model.getSong().toLowerCase();
        if (text.contains(query)) {
            filteredModelList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return filteredModelList;
}

 }
```

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

private int[] tabIcons = {
        R.drawable.ic_action_person,
        R.drawable.ic_action_group,
        R.drawable.ic_action_call
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new TabOneFragment(), "Tab 1");
    adapter.addFragment(new TabTwoFragment(), "Tab 2");
    adapter.addFragment(new TabThreeFragment(), "Tab 3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}


}
```

And lastly my ViewPageAdapter

```
   public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: does title_textview..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()); on binder function work? (from ItemViewHolder)

Answer (score 6):

1. Create an interface

   ```
   public interface OnHymnClickListener {
       void onHymnClick(HymnModel hymnModel);
   }
   ```
2. Pass the listener to the adapter

   ```
   public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemViewHolder> {
       private OnHymnClickListener listener;

       public void setListener(OnHymnClickListener listener) {
           this.listener = listener;
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) {
           final HymnModel model = mCountryModel.get(i);
           itemViewHolder.bind(model);
           itemViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   if(listener != null) {
                       listener.onHymnClick(model);
                   }
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```
3. Let your fragment implement it

   ```
   public class TabOneFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, OnHymnClickListener {

       @Override
       public void onHymnClick(HymnModel hymnModel) {
           //put data to bundle and startActivity
       }

       @Override
       public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           adapter = new RVAdapter(mHymnModel);
           adapter.setListener(this);
           recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: where should i create the interface?

Comment: I created the interface and added the necessary codes but i want the click to open a new activity like SingleHymnViewActivity.java

Comment: @winfredadrah 
Refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15478302/3123335, put those code inside the method `onHymnClick` in the fragment.

If you want to send the HymnModel to SingleHymnViewActivity, then the HymnModel needs to implement `Parcelable`, see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26757130/3123335

Answer (score 1):

Hello first of all you always want to start your activity from activity or fragment.
Never start it from adapter.

So in your adapter constructor add this

```
public AdapterName(......,Context context){
...your code.
this.mContext=context;
}
```

pass **context** there.

and than inside this method

```
public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mContext instanceof YourActivityName){
            ((YourActivityName)mContext).yourDesiredMethod();
        }
    }
});
```