# How to move from a fragment to an activity

Tags: android

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

//using startActivity(intent) is also not working
//the application crashes whatever I do

Comment: post your log,,

Comment: i think problem is in SecondActivity please post log for identify issue

Comment: in which method you call the intent.
please provide the crash log.

Comment: did u define the secondActivity in the AndroidMenfist ?

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
public void goToAttract(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivityList.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From a Fragment:

Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

From an Activity:

Intent intent = new Intent(this, mFragmentFavorite.class);
startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your SecondActivity is registered in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using a Fragment , not a FragmentActivity.

See this post [Fragment To Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15478302/4026510)